# python - using list slice instead of pop() causes UnboundLocalError

Tags: python, list, scope

When I use `while len(my_list) > 5: my_list.pop()` to truncate the entries in a list, I experience no error. However, when I use `my_list = my_list[:5]` to try to achieve the same end, I see an UnboundLocalError in an *earlier* part of the code, *before* the slice occurs.

I will try to only post the parts that seem relevant. First, one of the first things the script does is loads the list from a pickled file - if that should fail it is assigned a default value. Unless my understanding is poor, this list simply exists in the global namespace of the script.

```
try:    #either load hi-score list, or create a default list
    with open('scores.py', 'r') as f:
        scoreList = pickle.loads(f.read())
except:
    scoreList = [
                    ['NME', 15000], 
                    ['HAS', 12000], 
                    ['LDS', 10000], 
                    ['AKT', 8000], 
                    ['JAS', 5000]
            ]
```

Then later the list is checked to see if a new entry should be made; if so, player initials are collected. Otherwise the game simply displays the scores.

```
def game_over_loop(self):
        ##other unrelated code that only runs one time

        if ship.score > scoreList[-1][1]:
            go_state = 'get_player_score'

        ###...
        while displayScores:

            ###...
                if len(playerInitials.text) >= 3:
                    scoreList.append([playerInitials.text, ship.score])
                    scoreList.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
                    scoreList.reverse()
               ###here's the problem###
                    scoreList = scoreList[:5]    #bad
                    #while len(scoreList) > 5:   #good
                    #   scoreList.pop()
               ########################
                    pickleScore = pickle.dumps(scoreList)
                    with open('scores.py', 'w') as f:
                        f.write(pickleScore)
                    go_state = 'build_scores'
```

If I use the syntax between the comments, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sf.py", line 1024, in <module>
    TheGame.master_loop()
  File "sf.py", line 904, in master_loop
    self.game_over_loop()
  File "sf.py", line 841, in game_over_loop
    if ship.score > scoreList[-1][1]:   #if ship.score high enough, get_player_score
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'scoreList' referenced before assignment
```

However, if I simply iterate over the list while its `len` is greater than 5 and `pop()` entries, there is no problem.

I'm unclear as to how the UnboundLocalError occurs *before* the commented code. Since `scoreList` is global (right?) it seems like the worst thing that would happen is the local instance after the sorting and appending would be the only one that's sliced and then pickled, but it doesn't even get that far in the script before the error is thrown.

In fact if I add these lines to the script:

```
if 'scoreList' in globals():
    print "I see it"
```

Then I get the following:

```
I see it
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sf.py", line 1029, in <module>
    TheGame.master_loop()
  File "sf.py", line 909, in master_loop
    self.game_over_loop()
  File "sf.py", line 844, in game_over_loop
    if ship.score > scoreList[-1][1]:   #if ship.score high enough, get_player_score
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'scoreList' referenced before assignment
```

So how does this happen?

**UPDATE:** I appreciate the suggestions to declare it a global variable, but my question isn't "how do I fix this" so much as "why is this a thing with list[:index] but not when using list.pop()".

Comment: why not make scorelist an attribute of your class?

Comment: Sure, I could do that - this code is a way way old project of mine that I'm refactoring, so that may be a thing that happens. I'm sure that would address the issue, but it doesn't answer my curiosity :/

Comment: `scoreList` is not a global in that function, local variables are determined when the function body is parsed. When Python sees an assignment statement like: `scoreList = ...`, it sets `scoreList` as a local variable.

Comment: Also go through: https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/executionmodel.html

Comment: @undefinedisnotafunction - even though it's in `globals()` in the method, though?

Comment: Read the docs properly, Python won't even look into globals if it knows that a variable is local variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any assignment to a variable appearing in a function (not counting assignments in functions or classes nested in that function) causes Python to create a local variable of that name. All accesses to the variable inside the function will then try to access the local variable, rather than a global. Thus,

```
scoreList = scoreList[:5]
```

causes all accesses to `scoreList` inside the function to try to access a `scoreList` local that was never initialized.

When you do

```
scoreList.pop()
```

there are no assignments to the `scoreList` variable in the function. (The object `scoreList` refers to changes state, but that's not an assignment to the variable.) Thus, Python interprets accesses to `scoreList` as looking for the global variable, which is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Where is `scoreList` defined in the first place -- is it a local in that function?  The problem might be that doing `scoreList = ...` causes it to be bound with local scope.  Try putting `global scoreList` at the top of your function, in that case.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def game_over_loop(self):
    global scoreList
    if ship.score > scoreList[-1][1]:
        #rest of my code
```